# Unable to trim the last line in the Unix file

Tags: linux, unix, ssh

I am trying to create and unix file with some text in it with the below command:

```
ssh.sendLine("echo '"+"{1:F01ZYIBGB20AXXX0000000000}{2:O5481710NDEASES0XXXX12345678901511041511180930N}\n{4:\n:16R:GENL\n:20C::SEME//"+$TradeRef+"\n:23G:INST\n:16R:LINK\n:20C::RELA//"+$TradeRef+"\n:16S:LINK\n:16R:STAT\n:25D::MTCH//MACH\n:16S:STAT\n:16S:GENL\n:16R:SETTRAN\n:35B:ISIN DE0005933931\niShares Core DAX UCITS ETF DE\n:36B::SETT//UNIT/10,\n:97A::SAFE//8696\n:22F::SETR//TRAD\n:98A::SETT//20151118\n:98A::TRAD//20151118\n:16S:SETTRAN\n-}'"+">M548File.txt");
```

NOw this command is createing the file M548File.txt.
When id a cat this is what i get :

> ```
> {1:F01ZYIBGB20AXXX0000000000}{2:O5481710NDEASES0XXXX12345678901511041511180930N}
> {4:
> :16R:GENL
> :20C::SEME//11111111111111111111
> :23G:INST
> :16R:LINK
> :20C::RELA//11111111111111111111
> :16S:LINK
> :16R:STAT
> :25D::MTCH//MACH
> :16S:STAT
> :16S:GENL
> :16R:SETTRAN
> :35B:ISIN DE0005933931
> iShares Core DAX UCITS ETF DE
> :36B::SETT//UNIT/10,
> :97A::SAFE//8696
> :22F::SETR//TRAD
> :98A::SETT//20151118
> :98A::TRAD//20151118
> :16S:SETTRAN
> -}
> ```

However when i try to open the same file in notepad i get one extraline at the last which is basically an empty line making it a total of --  23 lines as compared to 22 in cat.

I tried the Sed commands but it just not working

Any idea how to overcome this to get 22 lines in notepad(same as cat)?

Comment: Read `man echo` and then use `echo -n` or `printf`.

Comment: Thanks indiv That helped. So dumb of me to not read the man